# Print element in list based on condition

Tags: python

```
car_file = open("car.txt", "r")

count = 0
for car_record in car_file:
    car_record = car_record.strip('\n')
    value = car_record.split(',')
    print((count+1),'.', car_record)
    count+=1
car_file.close()
```

[car.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwE3e.png)

I want to only print the line that [7] is available

Comment: You have split the values from each line. Have you tried accessing the fields of each record? There is also a `csv` library in python than helps here.

Comment: [7] what it means?

Comment: `if value[-1] == 'AVAILABLE': print(car_record)`

Answer (score 1):

Since your availability is in the last column, you could use `value[-1]` to access it. I think you should have a look at [if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) first. However, here is some code to help you out:

```
car_file = open("car.txt", "r")

count = 0
for car_record in car_file:
    car_record = car_record.strip('\n')
    value = car_record.split(',')
    if value[-1] == "AVAILABLE":
        print((count+1),'.', car_record)
        count+=1
car_file.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if string is in `value`:

```
print(value) if 'AVAILABLE' in value else False
```